# Cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken when sending encrypted message over network

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to send an encrypted string over the local network using the socket and cryptography.fernet library, but when the bytes are received it throws a "cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken" error. It does work if I encrypt and decrypt in one file, but not if I host the server and client locally or on 2  different computers.

Server

```py
    import socket
    from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
    crypt = Fernet('sqcyNL5kz2mxWb1KL2QSZWY-GCERE-scEgWBbvq9CCk=')
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind((host, port))
        s.listen(10)
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            while True:
                messageEncrypt = conn.recv(2048)
                message = crypt.decrypt(messageEncrypt, None).decode()
                print(message)
```

Client

```py
    import socket
    from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
    crypt = Fernet('sqcyNL5kz2mxWb1KL2QSZWY-GCERE-scEgWBbvq9CCk=')
    message = 'sentence'
    messageEncode = message.encode()
    messageEncrypt = crypt.encrypt(messageEncode)
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((host, port))
        s.sendall(messageEncrypt)
        s.close()
```

The client encodes, encrypts, then sends the message and the client receives the message and decrypts it. The server does correctly decrypt and print the message, but immediately crashes preventing the rest of the program running.
The weird thing is that it has enough time to print after decrypting before it crashes. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Console for server:

```
sentence
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Google Drive/School/###/###/python/project/morseSrv.py", line 50, in <module>
message = crypt.decrypt(messageEncrypt).decode()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 74, in decrypt
timestamp, data = Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 92, in _get_unverified_token_data
raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You don't have any framing in your protocol.  TCP doesn't guarantee delivery boundaries.  You might send "xxx" and receive "x" then "x" then "x".  Or the reverse.

Comment: Kudos on a well-written question. You might want to take @Jean-PaulCalderone comment to heart and learn about writing *reliable* code to send and receive data with sockets.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the while True loop in the server. When it received data it would go through the loop again, but wouldn't wait for new data. I've modified it to break out of the loop after it processes the message.